# Problems connecting to iTunes store

Tags: ios, itunes-store

Every time I open App Store on my iPhone, I am prompted for my password, which I do – and then, the message “Cannot connect to iTunes store” appears.

Here's the thing: Everything else network related works on the phone. I can browse the web, I can even browse the app store from within the App Store app, and I can update apps when required. I just can't buy any new apps.

I have tried everything on the following knowledge base articles, to no avail:

1. [Can't connect to the iTunes Store](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1368)
2. [iTunes: Possible iTunes Store errors](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1424)
3. [iTunes: Advanced iTunes Store troubleshooting](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3297)

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with help from Apple support. The resolution in my case was simple enough, if perhaps a bit drastic: I had to reset the network settings.

Settings → General → Reset → Reset Network Settings

Warning: This reboots the phone, and you have to reenter any WiFi settings for networks you use. Be sure that you have the needed passwords before doing so!

This may not be the solution for you, if you have this problem. Be sure to consult the three articles linked from the question first! But the network settings reset is an option to keep in mind if all else fails, and before you contact Apple Support yourself. (I don't know why this is not listed on the Advanced … page.)

Answer (score -2):

Try to have iOS 8 and then try connecting to iTunes. It should be able to connect.

Comment: You can too (if necessary )choose a different pass code.